# Как сделать чтоб при адаптации центр карты менялся?

Tags: jquery, yandex-maps-api

У меня есть карта, в ней указан центр, на десктопе все хорошо, но нужно чтоб на планшете (768px) и на мобильном (320px) центр карты (center: [55.759456, 37.626789]) смещался ниже..., так же по возможности менялся zoom.

```js
ymaps.ready(function () {
    var myMap = new ymaps.Map('map', {
            center: [55.759456, 37.626789],
            zoom: 12
        }, {
            searchControlProvider: 'yandex#search'
        }),

        myPlacemarkWithContent = new ymaps.Placemark([55.753180, 37.646609], {
            hintContent: '109469, Москва, ул. Братиславская, д. 22',
            balloonContent: '109469, Москва, ул. Братиславская, д. 22'
        }, {
            iconLayout: 'default#imageWithContent',
            iconImageHref: 'img/map_marker.png',
            iconImageSize: [57, 70],
            iconImageOffset: [0, -35],
            iconContentOffset: [5, 5]
        });
        myPlacemarkWithContentQ = new ymaps.Placemark([55.772616, 37.549178], {
            hintContent: ''
        }, {
            iconLayout: 'default#imageWithContent',
            iconImageHref: 'img/map_marker.png',
            iconImageSize: [57, 70],
            iconImageOffset: [0, -35],
            iconContentOffset: [5, 5]
        });
        myPlacemarR = new ymaps.Placemark([55.745002, 37.600256], {
            hintContent: ''
        }, {
            iconLayout: 'default#imageWithContent',
            iconImageHref: 'img/map_marker.png',
            iconImageSize: [57, 70],
            iconImageOffset: [0, -35],
            iconContentOffset: [5, 5]
        });

    myMap.geoObjects
        .add(myPlacemarkWithContent)
        .add(myPlacemarR)
        .add(myPlacemarkWithContentQ);
});
```

Comment: что у Вас не получилось?

Comment: Код правильно вставь для начала.

Comment: https://tech.yandex.ru/maps/doc/archive/jsapi/2.0/ref/reference/Map-docpage/#event_detail__event_detail/event-boundschange